# Do stabilizer operations map stabilizer states to stabilizer states?

Tags: stabilizer-state

Stabilizer operations comprised of stabiliser state preparations, Clifford gates, Pauli measurements, classical randomness and conditioning. Does stabilizer operations map stabilizer states to stabilizer states and why?

Comment: I suggest to verify that for every "elementary" stabilizer operation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - that's the definition of stabilizer circuits: They map stabilizer states to stabilizer states.

Comment: A small note: Stabilizer operations generally map stabilizer states to convex combinations of stabilizer states. Depending who you ask, the latter are stabilizer states or not :)